# Compare Column(data) from different table and view in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, compare, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to compare few columns in different view with table.

For example:

View a:

```
student_id    First_Name      University                 high_degree 
0011221       Tom          New York university             Y
0011221       Tom          MIT                             N
0011222       Peter        Harvard university              Y
0011223       Sam          Northeastern university         Y
0011224       Leo          Boston university               Y
0011225       Paul         Boston college                  Y (this is not correct)
0011225       Paul         Tufts                           N
```

table b:

```
student_id    First_Name      University                 degree 
0011221       Tom          New York university             MS
0011222       Peter        Harvard university              DR
0011223       Sam          Northeastern university         BS
0011224       Leo          Boston university               BS
0011225       Paul         Tufts                           DR
```

Assume that the **table b** is the most update student information, but in the view a it is the old data from different old table and some student fill the wrong information, then I want to find out which students's information is incorrect.

For example Paul studied two school, Boston college for BS, Tufts for Doctor. In table B is the most update student info, Paul studied Tufts that is the high degree. However in view a Paul's high degree is Boston college so this is wrong information. I am looking for which student has same situation. how to do that?

Ideal result like:

```
student_id    First_Name      University                 high_degree     result
0011221       Tom          New York university             Y             match
0011221       Tom          MIT                             N             null
0011222       Peter        Harvard university              Y             match
0011223       Sam          Northeastern university         Y             match
0011224       Leo          Boston university               Y             match
0011225       Paul         Boston college                  N             null
0011225       Paul         Tufts                           Y             not match
```

No need to same with ideal result, but just need to know which student in view a has different data by comparing with table b.

I appreciate your reply. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use outer join, while result is retrieved by `case` expression.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  view_a (first_name, university, high_degree) as
  3    (select 'Tom'  , 'New York university', 'Y' from dual union all
  4     select 'Tom'  , 'MIT'                , 'N' from dual union all
  5     select 'Peter', 'Harvard university' , 'Y' from dual union all
  6     select 'Paul' , 'Boston college'     , 'Y' from dual union all
  7     select 'Paul' , 'Tufts'              , 'N' from dual
  8    ),
  9  table_b (first_name, university) as
 10    (select 'Tom'  , 'New York university' from dual union all
 11     select 'Peter', 'Harvard university'  from dual union all
 12     select 'Paul' , 'Tufts'               from dual
 13    )
```

Query:

```
 14  select a.first_name, a.university, a.high_degree,
 15    case when a.university = b.university then
 16              case when a.high_degree = 'Y' then 'Match'
 17                   when a.high_degree = 'N' then 'Not match'
 18              end
 19         else null
 20    end result
 21  from view_a a left join table_b b on a.first_name = b.first_name
 22                                   and a.university = b.university
 23  order by a.first_name desc, a.university;

FIRST UNIVERSITY          HIGH_DEGREE  RESULT
----- ------------------- ------------ ---------
Tom   MIT                 N
Tom   New York university Y            Match
Peter Harvard university  Y            Match
Paul  Boston college      Y
Paul  Tufts               N            Not match

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, 
Thank you so much for the reply. 
It work very well!!
Thank you a lot !